# Click button + send user selected year + Ajax call + to open controller + Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Here im using a button called "Generate annual report" to generate a pdf.Pdf should be generated based on the selected year by user.So at first user should select a year and then click on the button.

As in the below im using ajax call to send the selected values to the controller called "Annual_reports_controller" and to view the pdf content in the "Annual_reports_view".

**In my view.php**

```
   <a class="btn btn-primary" id="button" >Generate annual report</a>


   $('#button').click(function(){
   var year = $("#year option:selected").val();
   $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Annual_reports_controller/index/",
   ContentType: 'application/json',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: { 'year': year},
    success : function(data) {
        },
    error : function(data) {      
    }

    });
```

**In Annual_reports_controller.php**

```
    public function index(){
    $year = $this->input->post('year');
    $this->load->view("Annual_reports_view",$data);
```

I tested Annual_reports_view.php using below code without using a ajax request as below.

```
    <?php $year = date("Y") ?>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="button" href="Annual_reports_controller/index/<?php echo $year;?>">Generate annual report</a>
```

This works perfectly.But in this case i have to define the year to open the pdf page.But the problem is i want user to allow select a year and then generate the pdf page. That's why i used ajax call to connect with the controller to open the pdf page with user selected year. But it seems not working.

Thank you! 
Any help appreciated, I am stuck on this

Comment: "it seems it is not working" is not a clear problem statement. what isn't working? what errors are you getting? if you aren't getting any errors, is error reporting on? did you look at your error logs?

Comment: also you can't get a pdf file to download/open (if thats what you are trying to do) from an ajax call like this. this is best served with plain old redirection. however you can use ajax for the form part up until redirecting to the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see is that your click event is not preventing the default action for an anchor.

So this line:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
```

Should be changed to these two lines, like this:

```
$('#button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
```

Next is that when using CodeIgniter, it is a common mistake for people to use base_url for everything, but base_url doesn't work well for site url's, because it doesnt know about URL rewriting that you might be using to take index.php out of your urls. You should always use site_url if you're creating site URLs. So this line:

```
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Annual_reports_controller/index/",
```

Should be like this:

```
url: "<?php echo site_url('annual_reports_controller'); ?>"
```

Notice that I didn't need to use `annual_reports_controller/index` because `index` is implied by default if you're calling a controller without a second URI segment. Also notice that I lowercased the controller name. While your controller filename needs to be ucfirst, that isn't how you create links.

Next thing I see is that you are declaring a ContentType for your AJAX request, but this is wrong. You can remove that line. If you look at the jQuery documentation for .ajax(), you'll see that contentType is used to define the type of content you are SENDING in your request, not what you want back. Since you are posting data, you don't need to specify a contentType setting, AND that is probably messing you up. Again, delete that line.

Next, it may seem obvious, but in your view it doesn't show that your javascript is wrapped with script tags. So:

```
<script>
    // Your code ...
</script>
```

Last, when you want CodeIgniter to respond with json, you need to output json. Right now it's impossible to see what you are responding with, but I will typically not use views, and instead do something like this:

```
echo json_encode([
    'foo' => 'bar'
]);
```

Which means that in your jQuery .ajax() success method, you'd be able to see the value of foo like this:

```
success: function(data){
    console.log( data.foo );
}
```

Hope this helps point you in the right direction.